# iOS webview error The operation couldn’t be completed NSURLErrorDomain error -999

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Receiving an error in iOS application when loading a request in webview.

The operation couldn’t be completed NSURLErrorDomain error -999 .

I am receiving this error in webview delegate sometime

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{

}
```

Still after receiving this error my Api flow completes .
Please provide comments why this issue is coming and what is the best solution for same ?

Comment: What you are loading in Webview? please share link

Comment: Actually its a link that has target url of server hosted in our environment . We provide userdetails and password and submit the request then we intercept the response in webview finish load delegate method

Comment: Certainly you will find your answer in [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSURLErrorDomain+error+%22-999%22).

Comment: This issue is irregular , means it comes sometime and then gone . Its difficult to reproduce . It is request cancelled that i understand but i am not loading any other request from my end .

Comment: Check that when you make the same request using CURL there are no server certificate errors.

Comment: Can i make a webview request using CURL to get more details about this issue ?

Comment: CURL is a command to be used in the Terminal. See: [ebook](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/) It can be used for testing GET/POST URL requests.

Comment: I have not found a proper fix for this as i  am not able to understand why a particular request is failing . For now just to put a workaround is like i am handling the error code in delegate method .  if ([error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled) return;